# How to improve my code about the growing of a bacterial colony (C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm coding a program to calculate the growth of a bacterial colony until certain point.

Given a "X", that will represent the initial number of bacteria. And given a "Y", that will represent the number limit desired of bacteria in the bacterial colony. Return the number of days and hours that the bacterial colony needs for reaching the limit.

The bacterial colony doubles each hour.

Example.1:

- Input: 1, 8
- Output: 0, 3

Example.2:

- Input: 1000 , 1024000
- Output:0, 10

Example.3:

- Input: 123, 3453546624536
- Output: 1, 10

If the hour calculated returns a fractional number, it must be rounded down.

So far I have written this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    long int binitial, blimit, day, counter=0;
    float  hour;

    cin >> binitial;
    cin >> blimit;

    while(binitial <= blimit){
        binitial = binitial * 2;
        counter++;
    }

    day = counter / 24;
    cout << day << " ";
    hour = (counter % 24) - 0.5;
    cout << (int)hour;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've edited your question for format. What it's missing is an actual question. Does this code work and give the right answer, but you would like it to be neater? Or does it give wrong answers? Or blow up at runtime? Or fail to compile? What help do you need?

Comment: My code is returning the right answer, but, i want to start improving my code, like reducing number of lines, improving organization, eliminating redundancy and unnecessary process, make it more clear, use more math and etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the loop by observing that the number of hours is Log<sub>2</sub>(Y/X). To calculate Log<sub>2</sub>(A) using the standard functions, calculate `log(A)/log(2)`.

You may need to address precision issues when going from `double`s to `int`s, because the calculations will be approximate. The final expression for the hours may look like this:

```
int hours = (log(Y/X) / log(2)) + 1E-8; // Add a small delta
```

Going from hours to days/hours is very simple, too:

```
cout << hours/24 << " " << hours % 24 << endl;
```

Comment: This is the strongest solution here, but in the event that he'll end up trying to do an operation per hour, he would need the loop.  +1 for maths!

Comment: +1 for maths! Great solution, it will make the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a long int for hour if you do the following:

```
hour = counter - (day*24); // The total number of hours minus the number of hours that are in each day.
```

I don't have a compiler in front of me but you can probably also do something like this:

```
hour = counter % 24; // this will return the remainder when counter is divided by 24.
```

Comment: And you shouldn't need to worry about counter%24 returning anything but an integer, since counter will never not be an integer.

Comment: Ok, but you can have 1/3, 1/4, 1/2... of hours, right? And with this possibility you will probably face real numbers in the hour variable. is it possible to hour variable receive a real number(ex. 30M = 1/2 Hour, so Hour=0.5)?

Comment: You are correct - but you're only ever doing counter++;  If you were doing counter += 0.5 or something, then you'd end up with 1/2 hours, etc.

Comment: Yeah, now i understood! You are right at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If blimit is always a multiple of binitial, the solution is simple:

`counter%24` will be always an integer, so you don't have to round it.
In case of `day` days and `hour` hours, you only have to do is:

```
hour = counter%24
```

Comment: Yeah, but it's not necessarily, there are another inputs that blimit is not multiple of binitial. But, if it's only use multiple numbers, this suggestion would be extremely valid! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you end up showing me a logic problem... because i need a code to compute ->only<- completed hours.

Answer (score 0):

A note on the method of calculation: you don't need to iterate if you're only doubling each time. You're just looking for a value of *n* such that *2<sup>n</sup>* gives the right result.

So, note that *ngenerations = log<sub>2</sub> blimit - log<sub>2</sub> binitial*

Once you have the number of generations (as a floating-point number) you can just truncate that to an integer number of hours.

Comment: Nice! Using log is a better alternative. Thank You for the suggestion!